# Distance between two polylines

Tags: algorithm, performance, computational-geometry

I want to calculate the distance *d* between two polylines:

[image: polyline-polyline-distance]

Obviously I could check the distance for all pairs of line-segments and choose the smallest distance, but this ways the algorithmn would have a runtime of *O(n<sup>2</sup>)*. Is there any better approach?

Comment: This looks like something [quadtrees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree) could be good for - but off the top of my head I've got nothing more useful than that.

Comment: Don't know the answer, but I'm guessing some quadtree-based algorithm must be possible, where you only compute point-line distances between nearby elements.

Comment: A bounding-box based approach might help. Compute the bounding boxes of partial polylines (e.g. points 1...4, 4...7 from A and 8...10, 10...12 from B). For each pair of boxes you can compute a min and a max distance and discard pairs that can't compete with the best pair, refining the boxes recursively until they all are 2-point (1-line) boxes where you can do the exact computation. Seems to be O(N logN).

Comment: In your example, the closest point is at a vertex of the polyline, is that just a special case - would the distance be zero if 2 line sections crossed but that there was no vertex at that intersection?

Comment: Yes -- if two segments intersects their distance is zero.

Comment: Based on the illustration, I understand you need to find the shortest distance between the two polylines, so imagine if we place a ballon in the middle then inflate it till it touch both, basically if the points are listed in two lists each, each ordered by their X and Y, find the smallest common gap then expand from there.

Comment: Reference to an optimized solution in Matlab: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/151455

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Divide and conquer:**

- Define a data structure representing a pair of polylines and the minimun distance between their [axis-aligned minimum bounding boxes (AAMBB)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_bounding_box#Axis-aligned_minimum_bounding_box):`pair = (poly_a, poly_b, d_ab)`)
- Create an empty queue for `pair` data estructures, using the distance `d_ab` as the key.
- Create a `pair` data estructure with the initial polylines and push it into the queue.
- We will keep a variable with the minimum distance between the polylines found so far (`min_d`). Set it to infinite.
- Repeat:

  - Pop from the queue the element with minimum distance `d_ab`.
  - If `d_ab` is greater than `min_d` we are done.
  - If any of the polylines `poly_a` or `poly_b` contains an only segment:

    - Use brute force to find the minimal distance between then and update `min_d` accordingly.
  - Otherwise:

    - Divide both polylines `poly_a` and `poly_b` in half, for instance:

      `(1-7)  --> { (1-4), (4-7) }`

      `(8-12) --> { (8-10), (10-12) }`
    - Make the cross product of both sets, create 4 new `pair` data structures and push then into the queue Q.

On the average case, complexity is O(N * log N), worst case may be O(N²).

**Update**: The [algorithm](https://metacpan.org/source/SALVA/Math-Vector-Real-Polyline-0.01/lib/Math/Vector/Real/Polyline.pm#L74) implemented in Perl.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your design. Not familiar with Perl, so could you show an example of how to compute the distance `d_ab` (the minimum distance between AAMBBs)?

Answer (score 1):

The "standard" way for such problems is to construct the Voronoi diagram of the geometric entities. This can be done in time O(N Log N).

But the construction of such diagrams for line segments is difficult and you should resort to ready made solutions such as in CGAL.

Comment: a voronoi gram is useful as a lookup table for finding the nearest point from anywhere, if these points weren't going to change and you had to lookup the nearest one from many other points it could be worth it to generate the voronoi to speedup the lookups. but I fail to see how it helps compute the distance between two polylines?